# cut off empty spaces

Tags: python, string

How can i cut off the last empty space?

```
a = ['Hello ','everybody ','! ']
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i,-1]=''

print a
```

Comment: this version doesnt work

Comment: Note that your question is ambiguous.  Do you really want only the "the" last empty space?  That would mean removing one only, even if there were two.  Or do you want all trailing spaces removed?

Comment: only the last position! thanks Peter

Comment: @kame, okay, but you've accepted an answer which does any number of whitespace (blanks, tabs, newlines, etc), not just a single space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution via [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> a = ['Hello ','everybody ','! ']
>>> [ e.strip() for e in a ]
['Hello', 'everybody', '!']
```

Documentation: [`string.strip`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) / [`string.rstrip`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip), [`string.lstrip`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) respectively

Comment: `strip()` removes spaces from both ends of the string, to remove only trailing spaces `rstrip()` should be used (see my answer).

Answer (score 10):

To cut off only *last* (right) empty spaces, use `rstrip()` method. `strip()` removes spaces from both ends:

```
>>> s = " abc "
>>> s.rstrip()
' abc'
>>> s.strip()
'abc'
```

In your example:

```
>>> [s.rstrip() for s in ['Hello ','everybody ','! '] ]
['Hello', 'everybody', '!']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print [x.strip() for x in a]
```

This is called [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 1):

The list comprehension approaches mentioned above would be the Pythonic way to solve this problem but they don't alter the list itself (ie. a). If you want to change those, you'll have to iterate as you've done over the list and instead of your assignment do an

```
a[i] = a[i].rstrip() # For stripping off trailing whitespaces only.
```

This is of course, bad style and I would recommend the list comprehension based method as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = ['Hello ','everybody ','! ']
>>> map(str.rstrip,a)
['Hello', 'everybody', '!']
>>> b = map(str.rstrip,a)
```